# Why am I getting the login screen in wp-admin->Appearance->Customize?

Tags: multisite, wp-admin, login

I have a fresh install of WP multisite. When I go to wp-admin->Appearance->Customize I keep getting this login screen. It won't help if I enter username and password, it just says "please log in again".

[From some research](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/46787) it loos like it's the scripts `api-fetch.min.js:2` that is not able to fetch the local site and in stead fetches a admin page

[image]

Looking in my console I see the following error messages and warnings:

```
GET htt**://the-website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/widget-types?context=edit&per_page=100&_locale=user 403

GET htt**://the-website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/widget-types?context=edit&per_page=100&_locale=user 403

GET htt**://the-website.com/?customize_changeset_uuid=57a4dc4b-4bbe-4a79-b5b3-c3a46b519420&customize_theme=gaimer&customize_messenger_channel=preview-0 500
```

I also see this in Fetch/XHR

`widget-types?context=edit&per_page=100&_locale=user`

Result:

```
{code: "rest_cookie_invalid_nonce", message: "Cookie check failed", data: {status: 403}}
code: "rest_cookie_invalid_nonce"
data: {status: 403}
status: 403
message: "Cookie check failed"
```

Is this a WP bug and should be reported as a bug?

Comment: What troubleshooting have you tried? Is it the first site installed on your multisite or there are already others installed? And are they working fine?

Comment: Hi @ray-happyforms I've updated post with error messages. The sites are working fine - including doing what I need in /customize.  Yes, this is the first multisite on my server. I have the Main site (mysite.com) and one subsite (sub1.mysite.com).  The error is when WP tries to fetch the frontend site into the IFrame.

I don't have these errors on my DEV environment.